# postgres psql script path

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am making a directory of useful sql scripts to use psql. I would like to be able to use them without having to cd to the directory.

Is it possible to configure psql to search a particular path for invoked scripts? Or do I have to invoke them all with fully qualified names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the startup file `psqlrc` for that. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#AEN88717)

> `psqlrc` and `~/.psqlrc`
>
> Unless it is passed an `-X` or `-c` option, psql attempts to read and execute commands from the system-wide startup file (`psqlrc`) and then
>   the user's personal startup file (`~/.psqlrc`), after connecting to the
>   database but before accepting normal commands.

Create the file (if it does not exist yet) and put the psql meta-command `\cd` in there.
Per documentation:

> `\cd [ directory ]`
>
> Changes the current working directory to `directory`. Without argument, changes to the current user's home directory.

For instance, put this in the personal startup file of your user `~/.psqlrc`:

```
\set QUIET ON
\cd /var/lib/postgres/script/
\set QUIET OFF
```

`\set QUIET ON` and `\set QUIET ON` optionally suppress a message from `\cd` for every start.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply place your scripts in your .psqlrc file:

```
\set uptime 'select now() - backend_start as uptime from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid();'
```

and then run the query in psql by prepending it with a colon `:uptime`

**OR**

if your scripts are long and you wish to better organize them then you could create your scripts directory `~/psqlrc.d` or whatever and then (for example) (assuming a *nix OS):

```
echo "select now() - backend_start as uptime from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid();" > ~/psqlrc.d/uptime.sql
```

followed by editing your ~/.psqlrc file to add:

```
\set uptime '\\i ~/psqlrc.d/uptime.sql'
```

and once again invoke the script by typing `:uptime` in psql.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 workaround approaches.

1. psql \cd command. cd your $HOME folder.

   sql>

   \cd

   \i git/my_project/src/abc.sql
2. OS soft link,

   $> ln -s ~/git/my_project ~/work/project/my_project

   psql

   sql> \i ~/work/project/my_project/abc.sql